# Thread with "while True" and "catch all exceptions" sometimes dies

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.7

Here's a simplified version of my app. I ran it for a couple of days and than at some point one of the threads died (Thread D). Which should theoretically never happen. Since it's in "while True" loop and handling all the exceptions. Any ideas?

```
import time
import logging
from threading import Thread

class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        logging.info(f"[self.name] Worker started")
        while True:
            try:
                for work in work_list:
                   logging.info(f"[self.name] Doing the work...")
                   work.do_work()
                    
                time.sleep(self.sleep_time)
            except CustomException as ex:
                logging.warning("Exception")
                time.sleep(self.sleep_time)
            except:
                logging.exception("Exception")
                time.sleep(self.sleep_time)


def main():
    workers = []
    worker_names = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
    for worker_name in worker_names:
        worker = Worker(worker_name)
        workers.start()
        workers.append(worker)
        
    while True:
        for worker in workers:
            if not worker.is_alive():
                logging.error(f"Worker '{worker.name}' died")
            worker.join(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Logs for D worker were like this:

```
2021-07-21 08:36:42,121 INFO - [D] Worker started
2021-07-21 12:58:52,649 INFO - [D] Doing the work
2021-07-21 16:52:55,794 INFO - [D] Doing the work
Worker 'D' died
Worker 'D' died
Worker 'D' died
```

While other workers kept on working fine.

Comment: it may crash during the loggin itself...maybe?

Comment: No, because in the logs you can see this: `[D] Doing the work`. Which means "worker D" was already in while loop before it crashed. Also I only started seeing "Worker 'D' died" after couple of days.

Comment: But, if it crashes while loggin in tne except clauses is where it would die.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. Yes that's actually a possibility. Even though my except clauses are pretty simple it's still possible. I'll log that too and restart the app. Thanks!

Comment: The dead thread is looping or blocked?

Comment: Neither. It is not running at all.